# How To Convert double/binary and vice versa?

Tags: php

I would like to convert 14.4689 or 13.3616 to binary data (bits) in php. How Can I do this?

Thanks for helping

Stephane

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php you can`t do it without data loss

Comment: @Bakudan: i don't think data loss is an issue here. OP just wants to convert to binary

Answer (score 3):

Use `pack('d',14.4689)` (double) or `pack('f',14.4689)` (float)

Answer (score 1):

look at the pack and unpack functions.

[adding example]

```
jcomeau@intrepid:~/rentacoder/harvard$ cat /tmp/test.php; /tmp/test.php
#!/usr/bin/php5-cgi
<?php
$packed = pack("d", 12.3456);
print_r(unpack("d", $packed));
?>
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.12-2
Content-type: text/html

Array
(
    [1] => 12.3456
)
```

Answer (score 0):

use this :

```
<?php
decbin(14.4689);
?>
```

Comment: `decbin()` is only for integers. if you tried reversing that with `bindec()`, you ruined the original number.